# Rollup including unnecessary server code in client bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, bundling-and-minification, rollup

Why is rollup including the code below at the top of my browser bundle? I don't think these references are being used anywhere from my entry point. It is some default includes from the node builtins?

```
import require$$0$b from 'events';
import require$$0$6 from 'url';
import require$$1$3 from 'util';
import require$$1$2 from 'fs';
import require$$0$8 from 'http';
import require$$1$1 from 'https';
import require$$3$1 from 'zlib';
import require$$0$7 from 'stream';
import require$$4$1 from 'dns';
import require$$2$2 from 'net';
import require$$6$1 from 'os';
import require$$0$9 from 'path';
import require$$0$a from 'crypto';
import 'tls';
import require$$0$c from 'child_process';
import require$$0$d from 'buffer';
import require$$1$4 from 'string_decoder';
import require$$8 from 'querystring';
```

This is my rollup config file:

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json"

export default {
        input: 'src/client.tsx',
        output: {
            dir: 'dist/public',
            format: 'esm',
        },
        preserveEntrySignatures: false,
        context: "window",
        plugins: [
            nodeResolve({
                browser: true
            }),
            commonjs(),
            json(),
            typescript({
                target: "ES2017",
                module: "esnext",
                outDir: "dist/public",
            })
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the `nodeResolve(…)`?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to some subtle leak of server-side code into my client bundle. Thanks for the help.